# I want to stop my jquery slider at the last image how can i?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here is the link : http://aydinfolio.com/Development_peppermint/

I want its slider to be stop at the first one photo and no play so it means no more loop. Can i stop it with java-script or how can I stop it.

Please let me know its urgent.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
        $("div.mydiv").fadeOut("slow", function () {
            $("div.mydiv").remove();
        });
    }, 2000);
})
```

Thank you!

Regards,
Syed Hassan Ali
Dimensionsxpert

Comment: If you only want the first photo to display, why use a slider at all?

Comment: I tried to stop it with java-script but it never stop it and loops continuously.

Comment: I want to see the eleven sliders at a time and stop it at the last on first one.

Comment: It might be a good idea to post your Javascript code here, so someone can find the issue and *help* you fix it.

Comment: I use this code:
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
   setTimeout(function(){
  $("div.mydiv").fadeOut("slow", function () {
  $("div.mydiv").remove();
      });
    
}, 2000);
 });
  </script>

Comment: Can you confirm. Is the JS/jQuery slider page called: `jQuery.prettyPhoto.js`?

Comment: I wrote an answer for you and you changed the question!! Your title now says "stop on last image" and your body says "stop on first image" - make your mind up!!

Comment: No point having a slider/timer when you're stopping on the first image!! Save the code lines and headache tablets and use HTML.

Answer (score 1):

This is a pure guess as to what you actually want. I looked at your webpage example, and looked in the JS file called **jquery.prettyPhoto.js**. In there it gives away a few clues, even though it has been minified!

I think, to find out if it's on the last slide you will need to add these lines in to that JS page:

```
if(currentGalleryPage == totalPage) {
  clearInterval(pp_slideshow); // stop slider timer
}
```

Give it try.

After taking time to write this, you went and changed your question, which totally changes everything - thanks!

**UPDATE**

Load your **jquery.prettyPhoto.js** Javascript page. Use 'find and replace' and find the the highlighted line:

[image]

And then add this line immediately after the highlighted section:

```
if(currentGalleryPage==totalPage){clearInterval(pp_slideshow);};
```

It's not guaranteed to work. It's very difficult to navigate around minified versions of JS and time consuming. That line can actually go in many different places in the script, I was trying to hit the donkey's tail.

Comment: I looked at his webpage's JS page and couldn't work out the compressed jargon, how did you do that?

Comment: Used 'Find and Replace' looking for a `setInterval` function and then found the variables `currentGalleryPage` and `totalPage` - simples.

Comment: @PaparazzoKid Can you tell me what exactly i have now to do with this code where to put this please I am new with jquery or java-script.

Comment: @HassanAli: I was wrong the first time, I just updated it again.

Comment: If it doesn't work or you're stuck, post the non-minified, full version to me.

Answer (score 0):

you could do something like this

```
$( ".selector" ).bind( "slide", function(event, ui) {
    var step = $( ".selector" ).slider( "option", "step" );
    if (step == endSlideNumber){
        $('.selector').trigger('slidestop');
    }
});
```

Not entierly sure it will work but its worth a try.

Comment: were endSlideNumber is the amount of slides you have.

Answer (score 0):

Ok you had stated the wrong plugin but here is a similar approach

set the option

```
changepicturecallback: function(){
   if(currentGalleryPage == totalPage) {
       clearInterval(pp_slideshow); // stop slider timer
   }
}
```

Comment: this should offcourse be added to the initializer with all the other arguments. if changepicturecallback dosen't work try changePage .